# Spark wholeTextFiles(): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: apache-spark, jvm, out-of-memory, apache-spark-sql

I'm processing a file of 400MB with `spark.wholeTextFiles()` and I keep getting out of memory error. I first used this API with a folder of files which has 40MB in total and I would like to know if my code works with large file, that's where comes the big file.

This is the configuration and I think I offered enough RAM for heap but still no luck and I'm just reading the folder and then write down with

```
files.saveAsTextFile("data/output/no")
```

and the command is

> spark-submit --driver-memory 4G --driver-java-options -Xms4096m
>   --executor-memory 4G target/scala-2.11/mz_2.11-1.0.jar

I compared spark sql, `sc.hadoopFile` and `sc.wholeTextFiles` and **wholeTextFiles** is the fastest and I think that's because `wholeTextFiles` tries to load the whole folder into the memory of one node, the master I guess and everything happens at RAM, so it is fast.

**HadoopFile()** load by partition, which will be as many as files number, even if the files are small and this read action is expensive.

**spark sql** will load folder to partitions, the size of partition could be defined with

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes", 32000000)
```

but if the files are small, it takes time to charge the files to each partition.

> Q1. why do I keep getting out of memory error?
>
> Q2. when spark load folder/big file by partition and return RDD, how
>   many partition has been read into the RAM? maybe non, and spark wait
>   for an **action** to load as many partitions as the number of
>   executor(or cores?) each time to treat? in that case, maybe we should
>   load big partition like 64MB or 128MB instead of small partition like
>   32kb?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please the entire the code ?

The `wholeTextFile()` is used when the **filePath** and **fileContent** would be required.
Something like *key -> filePath (C:\\fileName) and value -> actual fileContent.*

The number of partitions when `wholeTextFile()` is used depends on how many executor cores you have.
Here the number of partitions will be 1 or more .

Unless an action is called spark job isn't triggered.
It's a bottom-top approach / lazy evaluation .